# How can we expressed $\phi_n(t)$ in term of $ S(x) ?$

Tags: measure-theory

I have some confusion in Rudin Book , my doubt is given below marked in red circle[image]

**My attempt** : According to rudin book, before  the theorem rudin mention that  simple measurable function defined by
$$
S(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i\chi_{A_i},
$$

But here im getting confused that how $
\phi_n(t)=
\begin{cases}
k_n(t) \delta_n \space \space \text{if} \space 0 \le t <n \\
n \space \space \text{if} \space n \le t < \infty \\
\end{cases}
=S(x)?$

**My doubt** :How  can we expressed $\phi_n(t)$ in term of $ S(x) ?$

Comment: You are missing  the definition of $s_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\phi_n(t)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{N} \chi_{[k\delta_n,(k+1)\delta_n)} k\delta_n+n \chi_{[n, \infty)}$ where $N=[\frac n {\delta_n}]-1$

Comment: ..@Kavi sir why u take $N=[\frac n {\delta_n}]?$   why not $N=n?$

Comment: We have consider the intervals $[k\delta_n, (k+1) \delta_n)$ until we reach $n$. @jasmine